# Variable is appearing as "undefined" in debugger

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, promise, axios

I'm attempting to display data with axios, promises, and other ES6 features. This project works in prod, but after changing the API endpoints around in dev (no longer working w/ old endpoints) I've run into issues.

For some reason, the variable I'm working with (`kkUser`) is coming up as `undefined`. I'm not sure if it has to do with the different endpoints or something else.

#### Helper file:

```
const kkObj = {};

export async function loadKKProperties(obj) {
  kkObj.spUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
  kkObj._KKRestHost = "https://ha----dev.com";
  kkObj._BaseHost = "https://in-url.com";
// other code
```

---

#### JS:

```
import { loadKKProperties } from "./helperfile";
import axios from "axios";

function getDocFolders(kkUser, places) {
  return kkUser
    .userValidatedPostRequest({
      // stuff
      }
    })
// more code

async function globalInitPromise() {
  const kkObj = await loadKKProperties(); 
  const token = await permissionToCallKKAPI(kkObj.hsHost);
  const kkUser = new KKUser(kkObj, token);

    class KKUser {
      constructor(kkObj, token) {
        this.kkObj = kkObj;
        this.token = token;
      }
// other code

userValidatedPostRequest(dataObj) {
    dataObj.Params.SAMAcct = this.kkObj.currentAccount;
    return axios
       .post(this.kkObj._KKRestHost + "/myAPI/api/Query/Post", dataObj, { // debugger gets stuck here
        "query": {
            "__metadata":{"type":"SP.CamlQuery"}
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
          Authorization: this.token,
          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
      })
// .then
// .catch
```

---

#### Console:

- 404 error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m, are you referring to `kkUser` within `getDocFolders()` or within `globalInitPromise`?

Comment: You're not showing any code that references `kkUser.kkObj._KKRestHost` which is where your console shows `kkUser` as undefined.  We need to see where that specific code is and how that function got called.  Basically, we need to be able to trace back from that spot to where `kkUser` was created.  That's how you debug these things.